# PSQL Drop database with FORCE

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, drop-database

I'm trying to drop a database with force, but I get the following `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"`

```
postgres=# DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_database WITH (FORCE);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 1: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_database WITH (FORCE);
```

I'm using Postgres 16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg22.04+1) which should support this as far as I can tell ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropdatabase.html )

Any thoughts on what could cause this error?

**UPDATE**

Turned out I was actually logged-in in a cluster from an older version (v10). Migrating the db to the new v16 cluster and changing it's port to the default 5432 did the trick.

Comment: Works for me. 1) Are you sure you are connected to a Postgres 13+ database? What does `select version()` return? 2) What `psql` version are you using? 3) Did you copy/paste this query from somewhere else?

Comment: Works fine, for many years already. You must be on an older version. Check your database version.

Comment: Ah, you're both right. Logging in to the admin db I saw `psql (16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg22.04+1),` so I was under the impression that it was running v16.0 but running `select version()` I saw the db itself was in a v10.23 cluster. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: With the Ubuntu/Debian `pg_common` packaging the most recent version of `psql` will be used to connect to all installed Postgres versions. There should also be something like `server 14.9 (Ubuntu 14.9-1.pgdg22.04+1))` after the `psql (16.0 (Ubuntu 16.0-1.pgdg22.04+1)`. The exception being if the `psql` version and the server version are the same.

Comment: Since this issue and your comment I now understand the whole psql cluster/version situation a bit better. I ended up migrating the db from the v10 cluster to the new v16 cluster. Afterward removed and purged the old v10 and changed the port of the v16 cluster to the default 5432.